# How to retrieve an itemName from firebase and use it for a searchView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to retrieve itemName from Firebase and tried to use it for searchView. And I don't know what's wrong with my logic in the following code.

[So here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7soDe.jpg)

And here's my datasnapshot:-

```
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseItems.child("items").orderByChild("itemName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            itemFinalList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ItemInventory itemInventoryTest = itemSnapShot.getValue(ItemInventory.class);

                itemFinalList.add(itemInventoryTest);

            }

            ItemList adapter = new ItemList(SearchActivity.this, itemFinalList);
            listFinal.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And searchview function

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And here's my "itemList" class as this is being used in my datasnapshot:-

```
public class ItemList extends ArrayAdapter<ItemInventory> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<ItemInventory> items;

    public ItemList(Activity context, List<ItemInventory> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewCategory = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewCost = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCost);
        final TextView textViewCount = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);

        ItemInventory itemInventoryTest = items.get(position);

        textViewCategory.setText(itemInventoryTest.getItemCategory());
        textViewName.setText(itemInventoryTest.getItemName());
        textViewCost.setText(itemInventoryTest.getItemCost());
        textViewCount.setText(itemInventoryTest.getItemCount());

        return listViewItem;

    }
}
```

I can also create a new class for searchList where I change my data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //under class declaration do this:
   private ArrayList<String> itemlists;




itemLists=new ArrayList<String>();
 databaseItems.child("items").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String itemname=itemSnapShot.child("itemName").getValue().toString();

            itemlists.add(itemname);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(SearchActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 itemlists);
        listFinal.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
```

Try the above, put the `clear()` before `onDataChange` thats why it is not working,everytime you are trying to retrieve, you are also clearing the list. Put the `clear()` before to avoid duplicate values when starting the activity.

Comment: Thanks, but itemFinalList and itemname aren't of same types.

Comment: use an arraylist of type string

Comment: What about for adapter?

Comment: use an `ArrayAdapter` since you are retrieving only `itemname` . Before doing that try your code but just remove the `clear()` from there and see what you get

Comment: I've updated my post with "itemList" class. Please look at it. Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: tell me what you get when you remove `clear()` with your code, if it didnt work then just retrieve itemname as a string, use arraylist of type string and an arrayadapter should work 100%

Comment: removing clear won't do anything because the data types are still incompatible, even if I'm using ArrayList type for itemFinalList because my itemList class has a different datatype.

Comment: Also how would i go around using arrayadapter?

Comment: I received an error aka app crashed. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mu.organyze/mu.organyze.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.clear()' on a null object reference

Comment: try it now @somethingelse

Comment: It didn't crash. It loaded the activity and when I tried to use search bar it crashed with error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference

Comment: I really appreciate you being patient and helping me with this.

Comment: @somethingelse make the adapter global variable, under class declaration do `private ArrayAdapter adapter;`

Comment: @somethingelse great! if the answer helped please accept it for future readers, to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I did! You're the best